# How to set the argument for iconbitmap()?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.iconbitmap

I am creating an image viewer. But, I don't know how to set the argument for iconbitmap.

I have tried bitmap, default but it says default is not defined.

```
def open_to_browse():
    global my_image
    mainframe1.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=home, title="Select a file", filetypes=(("*.png"),("*.jpeg")))
    my_label = tk.Label(mainframe1, text=mainframe1.filename)
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(mainframe1.filename))
    my_image_label = tk.Label(image = my_image)

import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

home = os.getcwd()
#print(home)

mainframe1 = tk.Tk()
mainframe1.title("Image Viewer")
mainframe1.iconbitmap(bitmap= "NoneType:None", default= "NoneType:None")

button = tk.Button(mainframe1, text="Open the file", command=open_to_browse)

my_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
my_image_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

mainframe1.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide a more [mre].

Comment: AFAIK `iconbitmap` only works on the Windows OS. I also think it only works on top level windows (i.e instance returned by `Tk()` or by calling `tk.Toplevel()`).

Answer (score 0):

Put in the *full pathname*. For example:

```
mainframe1.iconbitmap(r'c:\Python32\DLLs\py.ico')
```

or, *keep icon in the same folder* where your project script file is present

```
mainframe1.iconbitmap(r'py.ico')
```

> Set bitmap for the iconified widget to BITMAP. Return the bitmap if
>   None is given.
>
> Under Windows, the DEFAULT parameter can be used to set the icon for
>   the widget and any descendents that don't have an icon set explicitly.
>   DEFAULT can be the relative path to a **.ico** file (example:
>   `root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico')` ).

edit:

> **iconbitmap(bitmap=None)**
>
> Sets or gets the icon bitmap to use when this window is iconified.
>   This method is ignored by some window managers (including Windows).
>
> Under Windows, the default parameter can be used to set the icon for
>   the widget and any descendents that don't have an icon set explicitly.
>   default can be the relative path to a .ico file (example:
>   root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico') ). See Tk documentation for more
>   information.
>
> If the `-default flag` is given, the icon is applied to all toplevel
>   windows (existing and future) to which no other specific icon has yet
>   been applied.
>
> In addition to bitmap image types, a full path specification to any
>   file which contains a valid Windows icon is also accepted (usually
>   .ico or .icr files), or any file for which the shell has assigned an
>   icon.

The iconbitmap function (or method, depending on the programming language) should be used to set a bitmap image to the window when the window is iconified.

On Windows you're allowed to set a full path specification to any file which contains a valid Windows icon is also accepted (usually .ico or .icr files), or any file for which the shell has assigned an icon.

Comment: I just wanted to ask you if I don't have an .ico file, then?

Comment: what you have ?

Comment: png or jpg files

Comment: I wanna ask is what is meant to be the argument of iconbitmap()?

Comment: relative or absolute path of your icon